# get twitter feed using only JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

All the examples I see use php. JQuery has the ajax function so it should be able to handle this.

Can someone provide a dead simple example of getting a twitter feed using only JQuery?

I have my app created and have generated my keys and secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work with just jQuery and https://api.twitter.com. The twitter API doesn't support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Origin) requests except for a few sites they control e.g. Tweetdeck. You can see this in the Chrome Network page in Developer Tools, look for the OPTIONS requests.

Request Headers

```
access-control-request-headers:accept, authorization, x-csrf-token, x-twitter-auth-type, x-twitter-client-version
access-control-request-method:GET
origin:https://tweetdeck.twitter.com
```

Response Headers

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:Authorization, Content-Type, Dtab-Local, If-Modified-Since, X-Act-As-User-Id, X-B3-Flags, X-Contribute-To-User-Id, X-CSRF-Token, X-Guest-Token, X-TD-Iff-Mtime, X-TD-Mtime-Check, X-Twitter-Auth-Type, X-Twitter-Client, X-Twitter-Client-Version, X-Twitter-Polling, X-Twitter-UTCOffset
access-control-allow-methods:GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin:https://tweetdeck.twitter.com
access-control-max-age:1728000
```

A browser like Chrome will make preflight OPTIONS request before attempting your request, specifically to stop you writing javascript on your own website that performs operations in javascript impersonating the user.

There are some Twitter proxy servers you can host yourself that will let you make API calls, but you can't just use Chrome, jQuery and https://api.twitter.com

Comment: Can you include the link to the proxy servers? I found a oauth javascript module that makes the first twitter api call. I'm going to try that and if I get a cors exception I'll mark as answer. Just need to test. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried any of these

https://github.com/timwhitlock/php-twitter-proxy
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweetserver
http://supertweet.net/